# Como posso resolver essa equação no SQL? X = (A - (B+C+D+E))

Tags: sql, sql-server, matemática, equações, columns

Eu tenho uma tabela com as seguintes colunas:

```
COD_PRODUTO|PRODUTO|UNIDADE|FAMILIA|ORIGEM|ESTOQUE_ATUAL|COMPRAS_ENTRADAS|CONSUMO_PRODUCAO|ENTRADA_PRODUCAO|ESTOQUE_MIN|CMC|DIFERENÇA|PREÇO_REPOS
```

Preciso fazer essas operações, agrupando por COD_PRODUTO.

```
DIFERENCA = ESTOQUE_MIN-(ESTOQUE_ATUAL+COMPRAS_ENTRADAS+CONSUMO_PRODUCAO+ENTRADA_PRODUCAO)

PREÇO_REPOS = DIFERENCA*CMC
```

Eu tentei desse jeito:

```
DECLARE @DIF INT, @PRECO MONEY
SET @DIF = (SELECT (ESTOQUE_MIN-(ESTOQUE_ATUAL+COMPRAS_ENTRADAS+CONSUMO_PRODUCAO+ENTRADA_PRODUCAO)) FROM #ESTOQUE_DIFERENCA)
SET @PRECO = (SELECT (@DIF*CMC) FROM #ESTOQUE_DIFERENCA)

INSERT INTO #ESTOQUE_DIFERENCA
    SELECT COD_PRODUTO, FAMILIA, ESTOQUE_MIN 
    ,SUM(ESTOQUE_ATUAL) 
    ,SUM(COMPRAS_ENTRADAS) 
    ,SUM(CONSUMO_PRODUCAO) 
    ,SUM(ENTRADA_PRODUCAO) 
    , @DIF 
    , CMC
    , sum(PREÇO_REPOS)
        FROM ESTOQUE_INTEGRADO
        GROUP BY COD_PRODUTO,CMC, FAMILIA, ESTOQUE_MIN
```

mas retorna esse erro:

> A subconsulta retornou mais de 1 valor. Isso não é permitido quando a
> subconsulta segue um =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ou quando ela é usada como
> uma expressão.

**Sou nova no SQL, e não consegui encontrar outro jeito de fazer isso, alguém sabe me ajudar?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu vejo que esta mensagem de erro deve estar sendo gerada por estas linhas

```
SET @DIF = (SELECT (ESTOQUE_MIN-(ESTOQUE_ATUAL+COMPRAS_ENTRADAS+CONSUMO_PRODUCAO+ENTRADA_PRODUCAO)) FROM #ESTOQUE_DIFERENCA)
SET @PRECO = (SELECT (@DIF*CMC) FROM #ESTOQUE_DIFERENCA)
```

Você precisaria utilizar uma função de agrupamento (SUM) para que o retorno fosse apenas 1 registro, desta forma, vai retornar "n" registros, por isso a mensagem de erro.

Uma das formas de chegar neste resultado que você procura seria inserir o "@DIF" dentro da consulta principal, e depois, com base neste conjunto de dados, fazer uma segunda consulta para poder gerar o @PRECO. Pelo que eu posso ver, você usa essa consulta para criar uma tabela temporária chamada #ESTOQUE_DIFERENCA.

A sua consulta que cria esta tabela ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
select *, DIFERENCA*CMC as preco from (
SELECT COD_PRODUTO, FAMILIA, ESTOQUE_MIN 
,SUM(ESTOQUE_ATUAL) as estoque_atual,
,SUM(COMPRAS_ENTRADAS) as compras_entradas,
,SUM(CONSUMO_PRODUCAO) as consumo_producao, 
,SUM(ENTRADA_PRODUCAO) as entrada_producao
,SUM(ESTOQUE_MIN-(ESTOQUE_ATUAL+COMPRAS_ENTRADAS+CONSUMO_PRODUCAO+ENTRADA_PRODUCAO)) as DIFERENCA
,CMC
,sum(PREÇO_REPOS) as preco_repos
FROM ESTOQUE_INTEGRADO
GROUP BY COD_PRODUTO,CMC, FAMILIA, ESTOQUE_MIN
) tabela
```